# ImageSharp.Web - resize image by querystring in Asp.Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware, imagesharp

I am trying to use ImageSharp.Web to resize images through querystring parameters eg: *http://localhost:5001/content/photo/img.jpg?width=800&height=600*

I created a new MVC Asp.Net Core 3.1 project, installed the packages and followed the [Documentation](https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/imagesharp.web/gettingstarted.html)

I tried the minimum configuration described and several variations, but it seems that the middleware is not intercepting the image request. I always get the original image and no error is triggered.

Am I missing something?
What would be the minimum possible configuration for this feature?

Tks!

**Startup.cs :**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDependencyInjectionSetup();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        //https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/imagesharp.web/gettingstarted.html
        services.AddImageSharp();

        services.AddImageSharpCore(
            options =>
            {
                options.MaxBrowserCacheDays = 7;
                options.MaxCacheDays = 365;
                options.CachedNameLength = 8;
                options.OnParseCommands = _ => { };
                options.OnBeforeSave = _ => { };
                options.OnProcessed = _ => { };
                options.OnPrepareResponse = _ => { };
            })
            .SetRequestParser<QueryCollectionRequestParser>()
            .SetMemoryAllocator(provider => ArrayPoolMemoryAllocator.CreateWithMinimalPooling())
            .Configure<PhysicalFileSystemCacheOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CacheFolder = "imagesharp-cache";
            })
            .SetCache<PhysicalFileSystemCache>()
            .SetCacheHash<CacheHash>()
            .AddProvider<PhysicalFileSystemProvider>()
            .AddProcessor<ResizeWebProcessor>()
            .AddProcessor<FormatWebProcessor>();


    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();         

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        app.UseImageSharp();


    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to

```cs
    app.UseImageSharp();
```

must be before

```cs
    app.UseStaticFiles();
```

What is happening is the built in Static Files middle-ware is kicking in before its even hitting the ImageSharp one.. the order you register items in the `Configure()` section of startup.cs is important as that's they order they run in.

Comment: It works! I thought just the opposite, that UseImageSharp() depended on UseStaticFiles() and would overwrite it. I also had to remove services.AddImageSharpCore() and applied the configuration directly to services.AddImageSharp() to work. Tks a lot!